# C++ "File format not recognized"?

Tags: c++, linker, dev-c++, devil

I'm trying to run the code located here:
http://r3dux.org/2010/11/single-call-opengl-texture-loader-in-devil/

And it requires me to use DevIL, so I installed it to my c:\usr\ folder using the Win32 installer. I'm positive my environment is setup to read from the proper \lib folder as well. My linker looks like this:

```
-lglfw
-gluw32
-lopengl32
-lglu32
-ldevil
```

Everything else loads fine, but when it gets to "ldevil", the compiler (Dev-C++) throws the error: File format not recognized.

Comment: Note that the compiler is actually MinGW, not Dev-C++.

Comment: @Billy: the compiler is actually `g++`. And an *old* one.

Comment: @Andre: MinGW is G++'s windows implementation. I refer to that as MinGW in order to distinguish from `g++` running under cygwin.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely the devil library wasn't build with the same compiler/OS/options/architecture as the one you're trying to build your application for. You'll need to build it from source or obtain the correct version.

Comment: Most likely built with Visual Studio. `cl` and `g++` don't read each other's import libraries.