# C, Arrays, file format not recognized

Tags: c, dev-c++

for our homework we have to compile the program we wrote in the school. I have typed it without mistakes(verified with my colleagues) and the program does not work, I am using DEV C++ and the error log says, *file not recognized: File format not recognized.*

I tried using integer and not double but it stays the same...I have no idea what is wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define VELIKOST 23
int main (void)
{
  double dPolje[VELIKOST];
  int iStevec,iVecje=0;

  printf("Algoritem, ki določi koliko elementov podatkovnega polja imajo vrednosti vecje ali enake od 10 \r\n");

  for(iStevec=0;iStevec<VELIKOST;iStevec++)
  {
    printf("Vnesite %i. stevilo:",iStevec=iStevec+1);
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%lf",&dPolje[iStevec]);

      if(dPolje[VELIKOST]>=10)
      {
        iVecje++;
        printf("Element dPolje [%i]=%f.",iStevec,dPolje[iStevec]);
      }
       printf("%i elementov polja je imelo vecje ali enako vredost 10.",iVecje);
       return(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: You do realize `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior, right? (and why are you trying to flush it anyway? `stdin` is an input stream… don't you want to flush `stdout`, rather?) Also, you **do** realize that `iStevec=iStevec+1` is equivalent with `++iStevec`, so you are incrementing the loop counter **twice** on each iteration? Furthermore, the "File format not recognized" error, if it's a compiler error, has nothing to do with arrays, not with your code at all – rather with your compiler settings and/or invocation.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant they find them in some tutorials.

Comment: Perhaps Dev C++ does not use the correct character encoding when reading the source file?  The non-Latin characters in the string literals might cause this error if the IDE tries to read it as US-ASCII or another incorrect encoding.

Comment: Check result of `scanf("%lf",&dPolje[iStevec]);`  --> `if (1 != scanf("%lf",&dPolje[iStevec])) break;`

Comment: Does  even a simple "hello World" program work?  It may be that your compiled code is not compatible with your machine.

Comment: Maybe related: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4443642/509868)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that Dev C++ doesn't support Slovenian.

Create a new file and try this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 23

int main(){
    double dField[SIZE];
    int i, larger = 0;

    printf("This algorithm, determines how many data field items have values greater than or equal to 10.\n");

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        printf("Enter field number %i:", i + 1); //Note I fixed this original code had i = i + 1
        //fflush(stdin); unneeded
        scanf("%lf", &dField[i]);

        if (dField[i] >= 10){
            larger++;
            printf("Field number %i = %lf", i, dField[i]);
        }
    } //Moved this above final output and return
    printf("%i field items were greater than or equal to 10 ", larger);
    return 0;
}
```

I expect that to work.

Either way I'd definitely change compilers. [Visual Studio Community](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) Is a great fully featured IDE.

Comment: @Janac9 Same error? It's pretty clear that this compiles and runs. I suspect that you have problems with your Dev C++ setup. I cannot stress strongly enough that you will waste a measurable amount of your life trying to get that to work. Is there a reason that you cannot change IDEs?